# Tinder like pan iOS

Tags: ios, pan

For the Tinder app in iOS, I assume they are using a pan gesture recognizer on the image view. How is it that another image is shown underneath the image the user has started to move? Do they have another image view and after the gesture recognizer finishes, dynamically set the image view gesture recognizer, and finally create another image view underneath?

Comment: try this out https://www.github.com/nickypatson/TinderSwipeView

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tinder-Like Swipe Animation for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852934/tinder-like-swipe-animation-for-ios)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards

Take a look at this.  It kind of breaks down what goes into making swipe cards.  The answer to your question is that there is an array of cards, with only 2 or 3 on the view controller at any one time.  When you swipe one away, it loads the next one underneath the others.  As for how they set the gesture recognizer, the cards might be a custom class where all the gesture stuff is already implemented, or they might reimplement it every time, but yes they do have to add the gesture recognizer each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom class of card with own gesture recognizer and create delegate with methods didSwipeLeft/Right. Delegate will get call back on swiping and move next card to the front. For code reusing you can create universal manager for this cards.
You can look at the implementation of card and manager here:
 https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this recently for the company I work for and decided to open source it.
https://github.com/skensell/MXCardsSwipingView

I used [UIKit Dynamics](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial), in particular the UIAttachmentBehavior.  So when someone pans I create a new attachment behavior (essentially attaching their finger to that part of the card) and add it to a UIDynamicAnimator. When they release their finger I move the anchor point of the attachment off screen in the same direction as the end velocity (resulting in a smooth dismissal animation) and then after 1 second I remove it from the view hierarchy.

Internally I maintain a queue of the cards and whenever a pan starts I attach to the topmost card.

More details here: https://github.com/skensell/MXCardsSwipingView/blob/master/MXCardsSwipingView/Classes/MXCardsSwipingView.m