# Xcode (IOS): Flipping card tinder interface

Tags: ios, xcode, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am fairly new to IOS development and I am designing an app with a tinder like interface. However there is a difference in the interface I have to build, before the user swipes right or left they can tap on the card and it will flip over to find more info on the back (Tinder interface with double sided card).

I know how to do the flipping and swiping without any issue if it was just one object like an image. But it will be multiple images, writing a few buttons ect.

In other words it is a view. So basically I need to have a view that can flip and be swiped left and right. When I completed the android app I did this just by creating a view that I was able to modify like an object.

However I am unsure with the fact that XCode uses MVC. In Android I could treat the view like any other object. So I am thinking containerview? But I am wondering because one view will be controlling the swiping and another will be controlling what is displayed on the cards.

So my questions are: Is a containerview appropriate for this? Can viewcontrollers communicate? and can multiple view controllers be running at the same time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tinder-Like Swipe Animation for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852934/tinder-like-swipe-animation-for-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great open source project that you can use to get started: 
https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableViewSwift

(I find this one much better than the standard tinder UI, however if you still prefer the tinder-ish UI, here's a good example: https://maniacdev.com/2014/08/ios-tutorial-and-code-example-on-creating-tinder-style-swipe-to-choose-views)

**Flipping**: 
There are many ways to get the flipped card but here's one: you can create another view and then segue modally to it through a button (either visible or hidden) or through a tap gesture, using the flip horizontal animation. It will give the same effect.

[Custom Flip Segue in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074979/custom-flip-segue-in-swift)