# Automatic swipe left/right gesture iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, swipe, gesture

Here is the thing:

I have a ViewController, inside of him I displayed 3 cards, each one is a ViewController and has a .xib, cards are shown like in Tinder App, like a stack of cards.

My question is, how can I make a swipe left/right gesture automatically without the user interaction?

The code has been written using ObjC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check this link https://github.com/skensell/MXCardsSwipingView

Comment: You have to add animation in your cardViewController and call it manually from your VC where you need to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tinder like pan iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993020/tinder-like-pan-ios)

Comment: also this one is very good library for cards view like tinder https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards